# Difference between func and overrride func in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance

I am wondering why sometimes a function starts with **func** and sometimes they start with **override func**?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html

Answer (score 4):

Have you heard of the [Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html) concept?

> A class can inherit methods, properties, and other characteristics
>   from another class. When one class inherits from another, the
>   inheriting class is known as a subclass, and the class it inherits
>   from is known as its superclass. Inheritance is a fundamental behavior
>   that differentiates classes from other types in Swift.

Basically there are three types

1. **Sub Class** when a class inherits properties, methods and functions from another class it is called as sub class
2. **Super Class** A class containing properties, methods and functions to inherit other classes from itself is called as a super class
3. **Base Class** a Class that does not inherit methods, properties or functions from another class

When you type `override` you´re at **number 1**, the class you inherit from are **number 2** and when you´re not overriding you´re at **number 3.**

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Very helpful for me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

simply ***func*** means your are declaring a function.

for example
 **func foo() { }**

***override func*** means you are extending OR overriding the function of super class.

for example
**override func suu() { }**

which means the function ***suu()*** has already declared on ***super class*** and you are either **implementing** that function or **providing more feature** !

Comment: Great thanks, very helpful! It can be difficult trying to understand Apple's iOS documentation sometimes. Especially for a beginner.